# Automatically creating unique variables in for loop?

Tags: python, variables, sqlite, tkinter

I'm writing here to ask if there is a way to make Python automatically create new unique variables in a for loop, within the context of the code shown below:

```
for row in customerdetails2:
    AA10 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    AA10.insert(0, row[0])
    AA10.grid(row = editnum, column = 0)
    AA11 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    AA11.insert(0, row[1])
    AA11.grid(row = editnum, column = 1)
    AA12 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    AA12.insert(0, row[2])
    AA12.grid(row = editnum, column = 2)
    AA13 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    AA13.insert(0, row[3])
    AA13.grid(row = editnum, column = 3)
    AA14 = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    AA14.insert(0, row[4])
    AA14.grid(row = editnum, column = 4)
```

So basically for each row that Python finds within customerdetails2 (the database it is gathering information from) I want it to make a new set of entry fields but with different names for the variables rather than all of the entry fields being called 'AA10', 'AA11', 'AA12', etc. Is this possible? If not, is there a plausible alternative that achieves the same results?
Apologies as I am still pretty new to Python, but thanks in advance.

Comment: why wouldn't you use a list, or even loop over the row[0...4]

Comment: Why aren't you using `list` or any other collection here?

Answer (score 5):

You could have a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of entries:

```
entries = []
for index, row in enumerate(customerdetails2):
    entry = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry.insert(0, row[index])
    entry.grid(row = editnum, column = index)
    entries.append(entry)
```

When you need to reference them, just reference by the index in the list.

If you need to keep the `AA1` prefix, try a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
entries = {}
for index, row in enumerate(customerdetails2):
    entry = Entry(CustomerEdit)
    entry.insert(0, row[index])
    entry.grid(row = editnum, column = index)
    entries['AA1{}'.format(index)] = entry
```

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a function that takes a iterable object and iterates through the object and yields both the index and the object at that index.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. The solution using lists seems to give me a problem where the program shows only the entry field from the 1st column/1st row, 2nd column/2nd row, 3rd column/3rd row and so on. Any idea what might be causing this? Furthermore I'm not sure what the function of the 'index' within this code is. Sorry, newbie to Python.

Comment: Added info on `enumerate`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that "customerdetails2" is a .db file accessed by sqlite3 within the program. Could this be significant in any way?

Comment: So long as you're not trying to iterate through the file object and instead looping through the results of a valid SQL query, no - that's fine.